# Linq query parameterised operator and column name

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, linq

### Web page user interface

I have an ASP.NET GridView, and in each of the column headers I have a dropdownlist and textbox pair that allow the user to filter the column values. In the DDL there are 6 operators and in the textbox the user enters the value to compare to. Example:

- Column: Quantity
- DDL selected value: "<"
- TextBox text: "100"

With these selections, the user would indicate that only wants to see records with Quantity less than 100.

### Problem

I bind data to my gridview manually using EF and GridView.DataBind().

In my data bind method I have the above three bulleted strings (DBColumnName, Operator, Operand) available for each activated filter.

The problem is when I try to write a Where clause for my Linq EF query, such as the below one:

```
Entities.Where(entity => entity.Quantity < 100);
```

I need to do the above but like this instead:

```
Entities.Where(entity => <DBColumnName> <Operator> Operand);
```

The DBColumnName and Operator are the problems as the Operand is just a string.

I realise that an alternative could be repetitively checking each control, but this is unacceptable as there are ten filterable columns in my GridView so there would be a ridiculous amount of code. Example:

```
if (QtyColumnFilterIsActivated) {
    switch (Operator) {
        case "=":
            Entities.Where(entity => entity.Quantity = Operand);
            break;
        case "!=":
            Entities.Where(entity => entity.Quantity != Operand);
            break;
        case "<":
            Entities.Where(entity => entity.Quantity < Operand);
            break;
        // ... and for >, <=, >= ...
    }
// And now this switch block for the other 9 columns.
```

### Solution ideas

- ExpressionBuilder class
- Type.GetType(string TypeName);
- Hard coded SQL statement, as the strings would obviously fit naturally into one. EF would be preferable though.
- Stored procedure taking filter parameters and return table data.

Thanks to all in advance for helping (or trying), it's great to have a resource like this available. If anything needs clarification just let me know.

Comment: The linked dupe introduces DynamicLinq and also a way to build the expression tree (as you imagined might be the solution). Hopefully answers your question too!